# How to redirect to page if locale doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can I redirect to the "/en" page if locale doesn't exist in Rails?

I use i18n and the next code:

```
match '*path' => redirect('/'), via: :get
```

but it redirects only for the path, but not for the locale. How can I use it for the locales too?

Answer (score 0):

in your controller
do something like that

```
before_filter :check_locale

protected

def check_locale
  redirect_to "/en#{request.path_info}" if params[:locale].blank?
end
```

Comment: it doesn't help me =/ I used it in application_controller, but nothing

Comment: Is this method is not called  ?